# How can I get WMI to return info on physical disks in Dell Poweredge server with RAID enabled?

Tags: raid, wmi, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I'm using WMI to gather stats on some of our servers, and I'm trying to get details of the physical disks that are installed in each server.

The servers are various Dell PowerEdge models. Windows' built-in providers is reporting on the RAID volumes and the logical partitions, but I can't find any way to report on what the actual physical drives installed in the server are (presumably because Windows can only see as far as the RAID volumes being presented by the controller, and has no information about what's going on underneath that layer)

Is there a Dell RAID WMI provider I can install for this, or something else I can do to gather these stats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to expose information about physical disks via SNMP with OpenManage:

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/svradmin/5.3/en/snmp/html/snmpc23.htm#wp1052197

Comment: This does indeed appear to be the only way to get that information, along with the option to run the omreport.exe command. I just check with OpenManage version 6.5, which is still not exposing that information via WMI. There is a way to enumerate all devices with WMI from the DELL server, which includes the HDs, but it gives you no information on them (other than the vendor model id), and you can't reliably filter them out either. Hopefully they will fix this at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know this too - I want to get the 'State' field as reported in the OpenManage Server Administrator (especially when 'Degraded').

The Win32_* and the Dell_* WMI classes do not seem to give this level of detail.

The only method I know is to use the omreport.exe utility

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\SysMgt\oma\bin\omreport.exe storage pdisk controller=0
```

Comment: Do you have a link to more info about the DELL_ WMI classes?

Comment: The most relevant DELL_ class I found was at \\MEL-APOLLO1\ROOT\CIMV2\Dell:Dell_CMDevice

Here is some documentation I have found:
Dell OpenManage Server Administrator Version 6.3: http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/svradmin/6.3/en/index.htm
The latest client OM is much better - hopefully they will update the server version will follow soon?
Dell™ OpenManage™ Client Instrumentation Version 7.4 User's Guide:
http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smcliins/cli74/en/ug/index.htm

Comment: BTW, I didn't find the documentation very useful. Instead I just used this powershell tool to browse the instances: http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2007/03/22/powershell-wmi-explorer-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Dell Open manager must be installed for this one to work.

get-wmiobject DELL_CMApplication -namespace root\cimv2\dell -computer COMPUTERNAME | select-object Name | where-object {$_ -notlike "*driver*"}

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you're calling Win32LogicalDisk

Check out Win32_DiskDrive, Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition, Win32_PhysicalMedia (in what I perceive as decreasing usefulness...).  I'm on HP servers, so YMMV.  (You could also try Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition)

Failing all of this, try ScriptomaticV2 from the Microsoft Scripting Guys to browse WMI.